# How to stay logged in after a test with PHPUnit, Selenium and php-webdriver

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

I am trying to run multiple tests with a shared session between them, starting with a login.

```
   <?php

   class ExampleTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

       /**
        * @var \RemoteWebDriver
        */

       protected $webDriver;
       protected $host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub';
       protected $browser = array (
         'browserName' => 'chrome',
         'sessionStrategy' => 'shared'
       );

       public function setUp()
       {
         $this->webDriver = RemoteWebDriver::create($this->host, $this->browser);
       }

       public function tearDown()
       {
         $this->webDriver->quit();
       }
```

My first test is a login, which works fine:

```
   public function testLogin()
   {
     $this->webDriver->get('http://localhost:8888/public');
     $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::name("login"))->sendKeys("logintest");
     $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::name("password"))->sendKeys("passwordtest");
     $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::className("btn"))->click();
   }
```

I then want to test a click on a table row (based on the value inside the row):

```
   public function testFranchiseClick()
   {
     $this->webDriver->get('http://localhost:8888/public/franchises');
     $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath("//td[contains(text(), 'TestPortal')]"))->click();
   }
```

Unfortunately I get the following error :

```
   NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//td[contains(text(), 'TestPortal')]"}
```

Which I am sure is due to the tests not using the same session (user is not logged in hence no access to /franchises page) because it works fine if I include these two instructions in the testLogin() function.

Any idea of what I am doing wrong? I still want to be able to use these "findElement(WebDriverBy::" things.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tests need to be independent, so that you can run one of your tests without any problem. That means that for each test, you have to perform a login, do your stuff, and then log out. If I can give you an advice, create a method login which you will use in your tests. In this login method, you will get your elements and interact with them.

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain me why is it so important for the tests to be independent? Since I want to test the whole platform to know what page is broken or not.

By the way, adding a login function for each test make the tests much longer to execute. 

Anyway, thanks a lot for you answer.

Comment: There are several reasons that are (kind of) linked. First, you have to be able to run each test without running the others. It can seem a bit weird when you think that you want to test the whole app, but in the future, you will maybe need to make a quick test and you don't want to run all the tests. Or, Imagine that a test fails because of a minor thing, you maybe won't be able to run the other tests. When they are independent, you can test the whole app and have the actual results of your tests. You still can ask if you need more information.

Comment: Take a look there --> [Selenium-tutorial](http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/automation-framework-introduction/). It's maybe not the exact same framework you want to create, but it teaches you a lot of good practices

Answer (score 0):

I used Selenium but I'm not familiar with PHP, is this tearDown() executed after each test or once after all test cases?

Comment: After each test.  "Once the test method has finished running, whether it succeeded or failed, another template method called tearDown() is invoked"